# How can i get Tailwind Intellisense to work with .html.erb files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Following most posts that I can find from people with similar problems I've placed the following in my VScode settings.json:

```
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "html": "html",
    "erb": "html"
  },
  "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
    "\\bclass:\\s*'([^']*)'",
    "\\bclass:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
  ]
```

Yet Intellisense still won't autocomplete class names as it should. In case anybody might be able to spot any conflict that I can't see my entire settings.json content is below. FYI when i change the VScode language to html Intellisense works as intended.

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": true,
        "scminput": false
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "html.erb": "html"//,
        // "erb": "html",
        // "*erb": "html"
    },
    "rubyLsp.rubyVersionManager": "rvm",
    "[html.erb]": {},
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "html": "html",
        "erb": "html"
      },
      "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
      "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
      },
      "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
        "\\bclass:\\s*'([^']*)'",
        "\\bclass:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
      ]
}
```

TIA

Edit: I now see this error in the VScode logs, anybody have any idea what's going wrong exactly?

```
[config/tailwind.config.js] Building...
[Error - 21:05:23] Tailwind CSS: n is not a function
TypeError: n is not a function
    at XW.exports.theme.containers.xs (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:173:1488)
    at registerPlugins (/Users/user_name/Documents/Code/Learning/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupContextUtils.js:660:61)
    at createContext (/Users/user_name/Documents/Code/Learning/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupContextUtils.js:860:5)
    at Object.module (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2950:6591)
    at b (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2950:10881)
    at S (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2950:4537)
    at P (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2950:9211)
    at Object.I [as tryInit] (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2950:4422)
    at KR._init (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2952:13103)
    at async KR.init (/Users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss-0.10.5/dist/tailwindServer.js:2952:7846)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in vscode settings.json

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.erb": "html"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks @van-ninh, that does change VScode language mode from erb to html, therefore get Intellisense to work. However for other config reasons I'd like to keep erb files' VScode language mode set as an erb file. Is there a way to get `"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {"erb": "html"}` to work, so that I can get Intellisense to work recognising an erb VScode language mode file and treat it as html for Intellisense's context?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your user settings.json:

```json
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
  "\\bclass:\\s*'([^']*)'",
  "\\bclass:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
],
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
  "html.erb": "html"
}
```

The first block allows the plugin to discover classes when using erb syntax such as `link_to`, `f.label`, etc.

The second block allows the plugin to be available in .html.erb files.